# Missing Network manager

Tags: network-manager

I have just installed 12.04 LTS but cannot access network manager. Internet access is ok.
I have a wired connection to my router but want to set up a VPN.
I have checked via terminal and is says network manager is installed but i cannot find it.
I'm running this on an older emachines desktop that was running XP.
I have tried some of the fixes posted on various sites but to no avail.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The `network-manager` package just provides the backend networking service - the GUI interface is called `nm-applet` and is provided by the `network-manager-gnome` package, so first step would be to check that package is also installed.

The `nm-applet` program should run automatically in the Ubuntu desktop, and create an icon on the indicator bar at the top of the screen - for a wired connection it will look like an 'up-down arrow' rather than a 'fan' that you may be expecting (which is only used for wireless connections).

If nm-applet is running but the indicator is not showing for some reason, then you can access the configuration GUI by opening a terminal and typing

```
nm-connection-editor
```

If nm-applet is **not** running, then you can attempt to start it from the command line as well, i.e.

```
nm-applet & disown
```

(the `& disown` puts it in the background and stops it from being killed when the parent terminal is closed). However you should attempt to find out why it is not running - it can be configured not to start via files in `/etc/xdg/autostart` or `~/.config/autostart` but that should not be the case in a clean install.